# How to extract text within h4 strong?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**I am trying to extract each "Overall Rating" (number value in strong tags) from each product page**
 https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/product/12082017334688--epiphone-les-paul-standard-plus-top-pro-translucent-blue
The structure goes as follows:

```
  <div class="col-sm-12"> 
   <h2 class="line-bottom"> Customer Reviews</h2>
   <h4>
   Overall Rating
   <strong>5</strong>
   <span></span>
  </h4>
  </div>
```

I am trying to extract only the strong values.

```
 productsRating = soup.find("div", {"class": "col-sm-12"}.h4
```

This sometimes works, but the page makes use of same class for different elements so it extracts un-wanted html elements.

Is there any solution to only getting the products overall reviews?

EDITED!!

this is the whole loop for my program.

```
for page in range(1, 2):
    guitarPage = requests.get('https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/guitars/electric/page-{}'.format(page)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(guitarPage, 'lxml')
    guitars = soup.find_all(class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3')

    for guitar in guitars:

        title_text = guitar.h3.text.strip()
        print('Guitar Name: ', title_text)
        price = guitar.find(class_='price bold small').text.strip()
        trim = re.compile(r'[^\d.,]+')
        int_price = trim.sub('', price)
        print('Guitar Price: ', int_price)

        priceSave = guitar.find('span', {'class': 'price save'})
        if priceSave is not None:
            priceOf = priceSave.text
            trim = re.compile(r'[^\d.,]+')
            int_priceOff = trim.sub('', priceOf)
            print('Save: ', int_priceOff)
        else:
            print("No discount!")

        image = guitar.img.get('src')
        print('Guitar Image: ', image)

        productLink = guitar.find('a').get('href')
        linkProd = url + productLink
        print('Link of product', linkProd)
        productsPage.append(linkProd)

        for products in productsPage:
            response = requests.get(products)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
            productsDetails = soup.find("div", {"class": "description-preview"})
            if productsDetails is not None:
                description = productsDetails.text
                print('product detail: ', description)
            else:
                print('none')
            time.sleep(0.2)
            productsRating = soup.find_all('strong')[0].text
            print(productsRating)
```

Comment: From your example, do you want to extract `5`?

Comment: yes, thats what im trying to do!

Comment: you can do `soup.find(...).find(...).find(...)` or `soup.find(...).find_all(...)`. If you have many results and you know index then you can do `all_products_rating[index_of_item]`

Comment: @paper123 what is the definition of `url`?

Comment: Please make sure your question details exactly what you want. Do you want only the overall review rating i.e. one number from each page? Or are you also expecting to retrieve the reviews themselves?

Comment: @sentence url = 'https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk'!

Comment: @paper123 O.K., Have you tried my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review info is all in a script tag you can extract and load with json. Simply enough to see how to fit that in a loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

url = 'https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/product/12082017334688--epiphone-les-paul-standard-plus-top-pro-translucent-blue'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
script = soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text
data = json.loads(script.strip())
overall_rating = data['@graph'][2]['aggregateRating']['ratingValue']
reviews = [review for review in data['@graph'][2]['review']] #extract what you want
```

---

Output:

[image]

---

Explore [json](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=08d3ebaf7c7045c5b0add8e575e858f3)

---

To handle no reviews you could use a simply `try except`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

url = 'https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/product/190319340849008--gibson-les-paul-standard-60s-iced-tea'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
script = soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text
data = json.loads(script.strip())
try:
    overall_rating = data['@graph'][2]['aggregateRating']['ratingValue']
    reviews = [review for review in data['@graph'][2]['review']] #extract what you want
except: #you might want to use except KeyError
    overall_rating = "None"
    reviews = ['None']
```

or, use an if statement:

```
if 'aggregateRating' in script:
    overall_rating = data['@graph'][2]['aggregateRating']['ratingValue']
    reviews = [review for review in data['@graph'][2]['review']] #extract what you want
else:
    overall_rating = "None"
    reviews = ['None']
```

Comment: That works fine! but the issue is that not all of the products have reviews, what would be a good way to make a condition within a loop?

Comment: Can you give an example product? I expect something still to be present in script tag to help decide if _if_ statement required

Comment: This is an example of a product that i am scraping https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/product/190319340849008--gibson-les-paul-standard-60s-iced-tea Thank you for all the help! would you suggest a better logic for the nested for loop to enter each product and scrape the information, as of now it loops through the whole array which slows the scraper down a lot!

Comment: you could use a _try except_ ... added example. Also, added an _if_

Comment: you might consider using session object for efficiency of re-using connection. I have a preference for select and select_one over find as I suspect (but haven't tested) it to be faster.

Comment: thank you so much for all of your help, it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/product/190319340849008--gibson-les-paul-standard-60s-iced-tea'

html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
try:
    productsRating = soup.find('h2', string=lambda s: "Customer reviews" in s).find_next_siblings()[0].find('strong').text
except:
    productsRating = None

print(productsRating)
```

Comment: I have a loop that, scrapes every product, enters into a product page, which is what i linked and i want to extract the products rating, description.